# Why do I have more row after the left merge and drop_duplciates()?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

`iso_selected.shape` gives the result: (257, 2)

`gravity.shape`gives the result: (4428288, 79)

and I merge them in the following way:

`gravity1 = gravity.merge(iso_selected, how="left", left_on = "iso3_o", right_on="iso3").drop_duplicates()`

`gravity1.shape` gives the result: (4571136, 81)

Why would I have more rows than 4428288 ?

Comment: The **iso_selected** may also have rows with the same id but different other values. Can you check it ?

Comment: iso selected has only two columns: "iso3" and "country".  Basically, I merge on iso3 to have the country names. How can I check

Comment: can you check how many unique iso3 are in **iso_selected**? you can use: `print(iso_selected['iso3'].nunique())
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need remove duplicates before [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by column `iso3_o`:

```
gravity1 = gravity.merge(iso_selected.drop_duplicates(subset=["iso3_o"]), 
                         how="left", 
                         on = "iso3_o")
```